# Using .NET Core Interface IWebProxy in a PowerShell Core script

Tags: powershell, .net-core

I have to retrieve the internet proxy server address (cross-platform) via PowerShell Core, so I can use the `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri <Uri> -Proxy <Uri>` command.

I want to get the URI of the proxy via IWebProxy.GetProxy(Uri).

Is there a way to use the GetProxy() Method from .NET Core IWebProxy Interface in a PowerShell Core script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first import the namespace by `using` keyword:

`using namespace System.Net;`

Then you can create instances of classes in that namespace:

`$obj1 = New-Object WebProxy;`

And invoke their methods:

`$obj1.GetProxy("https://www.google.co.uk");`

If you want to import classes from a custom dll to PowerShell you can use `Add-Type` cmdlet:

`Add-Type -Path "c:\mypath\my.dll"`

You can read more about `Add-Type` in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-6)